# Passing data from JSP to jQuery and plotting in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, charts, highcharts

I am reading a text file which contains data to plot a graph in JSP. I am using hidden method and passing the value to the jQuery.
I am able to retrieve the value in jQuery through an alert but when I try to split the value using .split(), the values don't split based on the delimiter specified.

```
<%
        //response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 10);
        String jspPath = "C:/Users/Desktop/Out.txt";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(jspPath));
        //BufferedReader br = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(txtFilePath));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        String lastline = "";
        while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){

            lastline = line;
        }
        String column3[] = lastline.split("\\*");




    %>
    <input type="hidden" value="<%=column3[2]%>" id = "filevalue">
```

jQuery part:

```
var a = $('#filevalue').text(); 
var lines = a.split('\n');
        alert(lines);
```

I am referring to this fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dsbvpkt0/7/) to create the pie chart. Here instead of the hard coded data I am trying to pass the data from the JSP. Since my data is not getting split, i m unable to proceed further.

Please help me to split the data in order to provide it as input to the pie chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things - try using val() instead of text() to get the value from the hidden field, and you need to quote the "\" in the split command (with an extra "\"):

```
var a = $('#filevalue').val(); 
var lines = a.split('\\n');
        alert(lines);
```

Comment: A small clarification. If you could see the fiddle, there happens to be a dummy value (year) which is being appended in the code. Can you please help me on how to eliminate the dummy value and just add the required fields alone !

Comment: I've rewritten it slightly.  I use slice(1) to remove the first item from the arrays: 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsbvpkt0/17/)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It is working now.. I could eliminate the dummy values! Thanks once again for ur help :)